# How to set pixels in Qimage and save changes

Tags: c++, qt, qimage

I want change some colors of pixels and save changes, but not working. 
I have this loop. First I print on screen true value: like 255,173..., and second cout print on screen zeros. Until here is good.

```
for (int i = 0; i < image->width(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < image->height(); j++) {

                QRgb pixelData = image->pixel(i,j);
                int red = qRed(pixelData);
                cout<<red<<endl;
                image->setPixel(i, j, qRgb(0, 0, 0));
                pixelData = image->pixel(i,j);
                int red2 = qRed(pixelData);
                 cout<<red2<<endl;
            }
        }
```

After this loop I saved image. When I reopen or read this image. I got default values.

```
if (image->save(out.c_str())) {
            std::cout << "save successful!" <<out<<std::endl;
}
```

Path is good. So I think setPixel not work for save function?
How can I fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is saving in JPG. Somehow this format change values and try making file smaller. I saving in PNG and my values stay like I want.

```
image.save("somefile.png", "PNG");
```

Answer (score 2):

You have problems with save/load, not with setPixel. May be you need to specify a format while saving, for example:

```
image.save("somefile.jpg", "JPG");
```

Comment: I don't have indexed format, soo I need solution for saving pixels in file. Here I got index-  out of range.

Comment: You have problems with save/load, not with setPixel. So you need to read about saving/loading images and formats

Comment: I found a problem. I put in answer.